# Java EE application with BizTalk

Tags: jakarta-ee, biztalk, ibm-mq

I have a Java EE application with needs to integrate to a BizTalk server.
I know there're bunch of OOTB adapters available. I have few questions need an answer to.

1. Is it possible for a Java EE application to integrate to BizTalk via an MQ adapter? If yes can you elaborate little?
2. Is it possible to talk to BizTalk via webservice, exposed on BizTalk side that my Java EE application can call?

Answer (score 2):

1. Sure, you can send a message to MQ queue and BizTalk can read the messages from there using an adapter. I guess it would be any non-Windows based queue so you'll need the [MQSeries adapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa547973.aspx). Not much more to elaborate, once the messages are taken, you work with BizTalk from there.
2. Sure too, you can [publish your orchestration as a web service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561883.aspx) and call it from any application. The schema that you define as input of the flow will be your web service contract for the caller applications.

Comment: Are they alternatives to each other? any consideration for choosing one over another?

Comment: @user4099249 I would use message queues where the order of the messages is important.   I would use web services where you want high throughput and order is not important.  Message queues can also be useful if you need to have your sending system send even if the target system is unavailable at times.  Web service if you want a synchronous response.